# Error when using array.sort

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview, sorting

I have a variable that has a list of song titles:

```
var songTitles = ["Song Title 1", "Song Title 2", "Song Title 3"]
```

I also have a variable for the author of the songs

```
var songAuthors = ["Song Author 1", "Song Author 2", "Song Author 3"]
```

Whenever the view loads, I sort "songTitles" alphabetically like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    songTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
    songTitles.sort()
}
```

Last but not least, I have a table view with a subtitle cell. songTitle is equal to the title of the cell. songAuthor is equal to the subtitle. 
Sorting the titles works out great, but the songAuthor does not match the songTitle. Like say that the song is Hello and the Author is AHAH and there is a song named Bye and the author Lala.

The tableview will display:

```
SONG TITLE - Bye  SONG AUTHOR - AHAH
SONG TITLE - Hello SONG AUTHOr - LALA
```

Basically, the corresponding author does not match the correct song. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You fix this by not using parallel arrays:

- Make a class `Song` that combines both a song title and its author
- Make an array of `Song` objects
- Sort the array on the field that you want

Now you can use `Song` objects in your table view, displaying its properties as needed.

```
class Song : CustomStringConvertible {
    let title:String
    let author:String
    init(title:String, author:String) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    }
    var description : String {
        return "\(title) \(author)"
    }
}

var songs = [
    Song(title: "Song Title 3", author: "Song Author 3")
,   Song(title: "Song Title 2", author: "Song Author 2")
,   Song(title: "Song Title 1", author: "Song Author 1")
]

songs.sort() {$0.author < $1.author}

print(songs)
```